# Prove this convergence of partial sums more formally

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+3)}$$ I want to show it converges and find the limit. I started from the sequence of partial sums defined as $$S_k = \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n(n+3)} = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{k} \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+3}\right)$$ by partial fractions.
Now, I have noticed that I have $$S_k = \frac{1}{3}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+...\right)-\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+...\right)\right]$$ and therefore I have $$S_k = \frac{1}{3}\left[1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{5}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{6}\right)+...\right]$$ which gives me $$S_k = \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{11}{6}\right) = \frac{11}{18}$$

So I know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_k = \frac{11}{18}$ and therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+3)} = \frac{11}{18}$.

But how can I write it in a mathematically correct way?

EDIT: All the answers were very interesting, however I would just like to know how a "proof" could be written more formally, I know the above passages are pretty bad, however I would like to see how someone would build a completely correct proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the line exploring the partial sum, include the upper boundaries of both sums,
\begin{align}
S_k &= \frac{1}{3}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+...+\frac1k\right)\right.\\&\qquad-\left.\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+...+\frac1k+\frac1{k+1}+\frac1{k+2}+\frac1{k+3}\right)\right]
\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)-\left(\frac1{k+1}+\frac1{k+2}+\frac1{k+3}\right)\right].
\end{align}
Now one can compute a formally correct limit.

Comment: Thank you! So would it be correct to write $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_k = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{3}\left[\frac{11}{6}-\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}-\frac{1}{k+3}\right] = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{11}{18}-0$ by arithmetic of limits?

Comment: Yes. As there are now no open-ended sums or sums with a variable number of terms, the normal arithmetic laws of limits apply.

Answer (score 3):

Hint

You can telescope by writing

$$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+3}=\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+3}\right)$$

Comment: How did you find that equality?

Comment: oh okay it makes sense, they cancel out!

Comment: how did you even see that? It's so easy now!

Comment: You have omitted a factor of $1/3$.

Comment: @Dr.MV This factor doesn't add any idea in the given hint so I left it intentionally.

Comment: You wrote an equality.  It is incorrect.

Comment: What's incorrect in the equality? I didn't say what's I wrote is equal to $\frac1{n(n+3)}$.@Dr.MV

Answer (score 3):

$S_k = \frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{11}{6} - b_k \right)$, where $b_k = \frac{1}{k + 1} + \frac{1}{k + 2} + \frac{1}{k + 3}$.

So $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} {S_k} = \frac{11}{18} - \frac{1}{3} \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} {b_k} = \frac{11}{18} - 0 = \frac{11}{18}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the limit comparison test and compare the given series with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$. Here $\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n(n+3)}} = \frac{n(n+3)}{n^2} = 1+3/n \\ $  which goes to 3 which is a finite limit. Hence; since $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges $\sum \frac{1}{n(n+3)}$ also converges.

Comment: I'd say this is the quickest one so far! Thank you @manhattan